# C# script for rebooting TP link router

Tags: c#, console-application, router

Hello everyone I am newbee in programming, and I need to create an C# script to reboot my TP link router to do so I used this code:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://192.168.0.1/reboot.cgi");
      request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Referer = @"http://192.168.0.1/DIAG_diag.htm";
    request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36";
    request.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Admin", "Admin");
    var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Reboot = Reboot");
    request.Host = "192.168.0.1";
    request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic QWRtaW46QWRtaW4=";
    request.Headers["Origin"] = @"http://192.168.0.1";
   using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
   {
       requestStream.Write(requestBody, 0, requestBody.Length);
   }

   string output = string.Empty;
   using (var response = request.GetResponse())
   {
       using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
       {
           output = stream.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }
```

But it didn’t do the job. Thanks for your help and attention.

Comment: It could be anything. It's hard to tell what is wrong with your request without having the code of the `DIAG_diag.htm` page. One way to debug the issue could be to use Fiddler to find out what's different when you make the request from your web browser and when you make the same request from your app

Comment: Accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @KooKiz Why did you downvote me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is far too convoluted.

Enable SSH or Telnet on your router.  Send a reboot command through port 22 or port 23 respectively.

Here's a VBS that does the same thing.

```
Option explicit
Dim oShell
set oShell= Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "telnet"
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.Sendkeys "open 192.168.1.1~"
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.Sendkeys "admin~"
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.Sendkeys "password123~"
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.Sendkeys "reboot~"
WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.Sendkeys "quit~"
Wscript.Quit
```